CSS is not updated in Shopify Media Query
I have the problem, that Shopify is not updating my CSS on some elements.
Here is my code
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .faq_content-inner2 {  
     display: block !important;
      
   }

output is:
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .faq_content-inner2 {
    }
}

strangely when I write in manually in the console the same css properties, the output is this:
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .faq_content-inner2 {
        display: block; //manual written in console
        display: b;
    }
}

When I set the css to flex, it just shows display: f;
Website to reproduce is this one:
https://www.jaykay-sport.de/pages/testimonial

instead of make div block use grid-template-columns: 1fr; to make it single columns for mobile devies.

Hi, yes but thats also not working. No css property is updating

update the query to this and then check @media screen and (max-width: 768px){

Tried it, still the same result :/

I think without checking the code, it is harder to check and debug. why this happens
